# Master/Detail flow - open list fragment in master area upon list item tap

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I've just created a Master/Detail Flow in Eclipse and I'm wondering how I can get my main list to open up a different list within the Master section when a particular item is tapped? I don't want the list to open in the Detail section. I've looked all over the www but can't find any relative tutorials.

"1st list" will open List A when it is tapped.

"2nd list" will open List B when it is tapped.

"3rd list" will open List C when it is tapped.

**MainContent.java**

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.content;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainContent {

    public static List<MainItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<MainItem>();

    public static Map<String, MainItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, MainItem>();

    static {
        addItem(new MainItem("1", "1st list"));
        addItem(new MainItem("2", "2nd list"));
        addItem(new MainItem("3", "3rd list"));
    }

    private static void addItem(MainItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class MainItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;

        public MainItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

Error 1
[image: error 1]

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.content;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainContent {

    public static List<MainItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<MainItem>();

    public static Map<String, MainItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, MainItem>();

    static {
        addItem(new MainItem("1", "1st list"));
        addItem(new MainItem("2", "2nd list"));
        addItem(new MainItem("3", "3rd list"));
    }

    private static void addItem(MainItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class MainItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;

        public MainItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(MasterListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        MasterListFragment fragment = new MasterListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.master_list_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**Error 2**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why dont you just put a onItemClickListener and then on the particular item you want the user to click you show the second list, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to replace the master fragment with a fragment containing the list you want to display instead.

Let's say you have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(MasterListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        MasterListFragment fragment = new MasterListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

}
```

So instead of

```
.replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
```

you will call

```
.replace(R.id.master_list_container, fragment).commit();
```

where `R.id.master_list_container` is a container (e.g. `<FrameLayout>`) containing your master `ListFragment`.

---

Looking at your screenshot, I think you need to replace `<fragment>` in `activity_item_list.xml` with `<FrameLayout android:id="master_list_container">` and then follow the steps I mentioned above.

You will also need to put the original master `ListFragment` in place by adding something like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.master_list_container, new ItemListFragment()).commit();
```

in `onCreate()` of your `ItemListActivity`.

Comment: OK, followed what you mentioned but still getting a few errors + unsure what to replace `ARG_ITEM_ID` with. Check my screenshots above under **Error 2**.